# ADF regression in r statistical package

Tags: r

Please how do i conduct adf regression in r. to be precise i need the codes used in conducting adf regression in r. I am working on time series data and i need to determine how many lags to include in the adf unit roots test.I have tried to perform the unit root tests with a random selection of lags but i am not convinced its the correct thing to do.  I will appreciate a prompt response as i have to hand in the paper by Friday.

Many thanks

Funmi

Comment: If your question is one of understanding ADF regression, it would be on topic here, but if it's *purely* about code - syntax with no statistical issue - it's probably off topic and likely to be closed (and as phrased, would be off topic at SO as well). If you're dealing with coursework for some subject you should make that explicit (include the `self-study` tag, and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) so that you can amend your question to fit the requirements here.

Comment: Function `adf.test` from "tseries" package selects the lag automatically: `k = trunc((length(x)-1)^(1/3))` where `x` is the time series being tested and `k` is the lag length. See more [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/tseries/docs/adf.test).
Function `ur.df` from "urca" package allows to select the lag by AIC or BIC by setting the argument `selectlags="AIC"` or `selectlags="BIC"`; the maximum number of lags considered is set by argument `lags`. The function also allows a fixed lag. See more [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/urca/docs/ur.df).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for the adf.test() function in the tseries package in R, the default lag order used is "trunc((length(x)-1)^(1/3)) corresponds to the suggested upper bound on the rate at which the number of lags, k, should be made to grow with the sample size for the general ARMA(p,q) setup." That might be a good place to start.

There is more information about the lag order here: [Understanding the k lag in R's augmented Dickey Fuller test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7929/understanding-the-k-lag-in-rs-augmented-dickey-fuller-test)